# Lucene Syntax For More Complicated Queries

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

I am developing a website for my company, that allows users to query a database in order to get the information they need.

Currently, the users are used to a particular form of queries, and I don't want to make them change the way they are used to. Therefore, I need to convert their query to Lucene's query syntax.

There are some cases which I'm not sure what is the best way to implement them using Lucene syntax, I was wondering maybe you have some better ideas:

```
"Current Query"   :  serverRole=~'(ServerOne|ServerTwo|ServerThree)'

"Lucene Suggested":  (serverRole:*ServerOne* OR serverRole:*ServerTwo* OR serverRole:*ServerThree*)
```

Take into account that I'm using Regex to convert these queries, so one of the difficulties I'm facing for example, is how to do it if the number of elements `(ServerOne|ServerTwo|ServerThree.....)` is dynamic:

```
luceneQuery = currentQuery
                .replace(/(==~|=~)('|")([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\|)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)('|")/g, ':*$3 OR $5*')
```

Another query for example:

```
"Current Query"   : OS=~'SLES1[12]'

"Lucene Suggested": (OS:*SLES11* OR OS:*SLES12*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomand you to check BooleanQuery() on Lucene to create more complex queries like Wildcard , Term, Fuzzy U can include all by using Occur parameter while u build your queries. As an example

```
 Query query1 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("contents", "*ServerOne*"));
 Query query2 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("contents", "*ServerTwo*"));

 BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .build();
```

There is also regex queries you can directly run but when your indexed field will be complicates it taking time to find regex match